# For loop to populate a new column with previous date

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop

I need help..i'm trying to create a column where the new column is a previous date taken from date column..The result should resemble something like this..

```
description    date               count  previous date
abc               2010-01-05        1        NaT
khl                2010-01-08        3      2010-01-05 
nop               2010-01-10        6      2010-01-08
```

This is what I have done and my for loop seems to produce no results, it keeps on running forever I tried it many times.

```
skus=prod_by_date.Description.value_counts()

#Create empty dataframe
new_df= pd.DataFrame()

`for sku in skus:
    a=prod_by_date[prod_by_date.Description==skus[0]]
    a['previous_date']=a['date'].shift(1)
    new_df=pd.concat([new_df,a],axis=0)`
```

Comment: Your example and your code imply different aims. Are you sure you don't just look for `df['previous_date']=df['date'].shift()`? Your code implies some groupwise date shift but this has not been specified in your task description.

Comment: I'm fairly new to coding..I may have done something wrong in code, what changes do I need to make in code so that I get the desired results..Another thing can the results be obtained from any other way apart from using for loop...I get so confused doing loops and functions

Comment: We don't know what the desired outcome is, and you do not provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: I already showed the desired output in the tabular format above.

Comment: In this case, I showed you already how to get the desired output for a dataframe called `df`.